# Struggling to make a neural network mimic a basic if statement

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I want to make a neural network that can satisfy the following conditions but the neural network would never get close to converging. It was a ReLu neural network with sigmoid on the output

`If X < 0.95 output 0 
If X > 1.05 output 0
Else output 1`

I made a neural network with multiple layers and provided it with the input and output tensors below. The output for all the inputs was just 0.33 for any of the inputs. 
I increased to 9 data examples and got the same output.

```
INPUTS = [[0.95], [1], [1.05]]
OUTPUTS = [[0], [1], [0]]
```

It would converge if I provided data for any 2 of the 3 if statements.

Is there a fundamental limitations of neural networks to solve this? Or should it be possible and I'm probably doing something wrong?

PS I used Python & TensorFlow. The code is below

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
INPUTS_AMOUNT = 1
HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT = 10
HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT_2 = 10
OUTPUTS_AMOUNT = 1

# define placeholder for input and output
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, INPUTS_AMOUNT], name="x-input")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,OUTPUTS_AMOUNT], name="y-input")

# Since we're using a relu, the weights are initiated appropriately to avoid dead (-ve) neurons
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([INPUTS_AMOUNT, HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT], 0.001, .01))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT]))
hidden  = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x_,W) + b)

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT, HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT_2], 0.001, .01))
b1= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT_2]))
hidden1  = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden,W1) + b1)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT_2,OUTPUTS_AMOUNT], -1, 1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([OUTPUTS_AMOUNT]))
hidden2 = tf.matmul(hidden1, W2) + b2
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(hidden2)
# Training function allows for error calculations for value between 0 and 1
cost = tf.reduce_mean(( (y_ * tf.log(y)) +
((1 - y_) * tf.log(1.0 - y)) ) * -1)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

# Specify the data to go into the placeholders
INS = [[0.9], [1.0], [1.1]]
OUTS = [ [0], [1], [0]]
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
# Train on the input data, doesn't actually need 100000 to converge
for i in range(100000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_: [INS[i%3]], y_: [OUTS[i%3]]})
    if i % 2000 == 0:
        print('Output for debugging', sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_: INS, y_: OUTS}))
```

Comment: But what kind of outputs DID you receive? I also don't know what kind of language you're using to set this up, but I don't think you're giving it enough test cases. You should randomize them as well, have a1/3 chance of the test case being below 0.95, 1/3 between 0.95 and 1.05 and a 1/3 chance of it being above 1.05

Comment: Did you remember to normalize the inputs?

Comment: @ThomasW I updated the question. It pretty much output 0.33 regardless of input and I tried with 9 inputs. Language & Framework are Python and TensorFlow

Comment: @Flounderer how would I normalize the inputs here?

Comment: Are you sure your network will always output 0? Is your question correct?

Comment: You only need a simple single layer with at most a few neutrons to complete your network. What do you have?

Comment: @StudentT sorry made a mistake, it should output 1 for one of the if statments, fixed it up.

Comment: @StudentT I've attached the Tensorflow code

Comment: @tt_Gantz I would try subtracting 1 from each of the inputs. I don't know if it will help, but for some implementations of neural networks, it does.

Comment: @Flounderer tried subtracting 1, didn't help. I added bias nodes so they should learn to normalise the inputs if normalisation is something simple like a subtraction/addition

Answer (score 4):

The curvature of the cost surface with these particular inputs and outputs makes this a bit of a pathological example. A 'good' solution can be found by just outputting 0.333 all the time, and if you take a small step away from this solution for one of the inputs in the correct direction, it's probably often being cancelled out by a large increase in cost for one of the other inputs.

Still, if you make your weights initialisation more sensible (should be centred at zero) and standardise your inputs, then you can get this to work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
INPUTS_AMOUNT = 1
HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT = 10
HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT_2 = 10
OUTPUTS_AMOUNT = 1

# define placeholder for input and output
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, INPUTS_AMOUNT], name="x-input")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,OUTPUTS_AMOUNT], name="y-input")

# Since we're using a relu, the weights are initiated appropriately to avoid dead (-ve) neurons
### FIX WEIGHTS INITIALISATION
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([INPUTS_AMOUNT, HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT], -0.1, 0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT]))
hidden  = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x_,W) + b)

### FIX WEIGHTS INITIALISATION
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT, HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT_2], -0.1, 0.1))
b1= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT_2]))
hidden1  = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden,W1) + b1)
### FIX WEIGHTS INITIALISATION
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([HIDDEN_NODES_AMOUNT_2,OUTPUTS_AMOUNT], -0.1, 0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([OUTPUTS_AMOUNT]))
hidden2 = tf.matmul(hidden1, W2) + b2
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(hidden2)
# Training function allows for error calculations for value between 0 and 1
cost = tf.reduce_mean(( (y_ * tf.log(y)) + ((1 - y_) * tf.log(1.0 - y)) ) * -1)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

# Specify the data to go into the placeholders
INS = [[0.9], [1.0], [1.1]]
### Z-SCORE INPUTS
INS = np.array(INS)
INS = (INS-INS.mean())/INS.std()
OUTS = [ [0], [1], [0]]
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
# Train on the input data, doesn't actually need 100000 to converge
for i in range(100000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_: [INS[i%3]], y_: [OUTS[i%3]]})
    if i % 2000 == 0:
        print('Output for debugging', sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_: INS, y_: OUTS}))
```